# Mac Activation lock not able to enable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, activation-lock

My Macbook Pro 2019 with a T2 security chip is not able to turn on the activation lock. This Macbook Pro is DEP enrolled with an active MDM profile. I've double check these settings are correct:

1. Secure Boot To Full Security
2. Turn On Find My Mac

But I am still not able to enable activation lock on this mac. Do I miss anything?

[image]

Comment: Did you disable SIP?

Comment: @Salocor No, I tried on many MacBooks. None of them were turned off SIP manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is the official system requirements to enable activation lock: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208987#requirements.

Based on your explanation above, you might want to check 2FA on your appleid

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks! But I do have a 2FA account on my Apple ID that used to log in to the computers.